# Not able to load certain part of page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi, I have a html page with a div tag that is being populated dynamically using javascript. Now, I have to open only the contents of the div tag in another page and I am not able to do that. I have tried using iframes, jquery load etc. but nothing is working.
Either the whole page is displayed or the empty div (before execution of javascript)is displayed.

So, is there anyway to make sure that when the required page is loaded on different page , the javascript is already executed, so that when the contents of div are captured, it is already populated.

Comment: Could you edit your question please and add the relevant html and script code you tried and have issues with? This will make helping you easier and prevent us from guessing and assuming to much. In additon, adding a fiddle on jsFiddle.net also helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to populate your div tags with PHP, before it reaches the browser.

Answer (score 0):

set a variable with the html content of the div, pass that variable to the server and display in another page..

var foo = htmlcode

later

window.location(web.page.dir?phpvariable=foo)

in the new page

echo phpvariable --this variable have the html code you want